# Removing unwanted nodes from wxs file by applying xslt tranfsormation

Tags: xml, xslt, wix, heat

I am trying to cleanup wxs file generated by heat.exe by applying xml transformations.

Below is an example file output of heat.exe.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
            <DirectoryRef Id="APPFOLDER">
                <Component Id="cmp78E9FF58917B1844F3E9315A285F3147" Guid="SOME-GUID">
                    <File Id="fil093D6D7CB723B5B62730D7B4E575F154" KeyPath="yes" Source="PQR.Some.dll" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp0B084126FAE7577FD84DB29766AC6C2B" Guid="SOME-GUID">
                    <File Id="filB20C8708D7EB02EDFBCC4D70F9FE7F8A" KeyPath="yes" Source="ABC.Another.dll" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp83BB1954DECD7D949AAE4ACA68806EC3" Guid="SOME-GUID">
                    <File Id="fil0E29FBFF7DB39F307A2EE19237A0A579" KeyPath="yes" Source="ABC.OneMore.dll" />
                </Component>
            </DirectoryRef>
        </Fragment>
        <Fragment>
            <ComponentGroup Id="AppFiles">
                <ComponentRef Id="cmp78E9FF58917B1844F3E9315A285F3147" />
                <ComponentRef Id="cmp0B084126FAE7577FD84DB29766AC6C2B" />
                <ComponentRef Id="cmp83BB1954DECD7D949AAE4ACA68806EC3" />
            </ComponentGroup>
        </Fragment>
    </Wix>
```

I want to remove Component nodes whose child File node having a Source attribute containing the string 'ABC'. I know how to find such nodes using the correct matching patterns.
So before I remove the Component node, I want to store the Id of the component and then use it to remove the ComponentRef node with the Id which i just recorded.

Is there a way I can acheive this with XML transformation? I think I am looking for something where I can create a variable say 'X' to store the Id of Component node that I delete, and use 'X' to find the ComponentRef nodes to be deleted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this without variables. Like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:wi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="kCompsToRemove"
           match="wi:Component[contains(wi:File/@Source, 'ABC')]"
           use="@Id" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[self::wi:Component or self::wi:ComponentRef]
                        [key('kCompsToRemove', @Id)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="APPFOLDER">
      <Component Id="cmp78E9FF58917B1844F3E9315A285F3147" Guid="SOME-GUID">
        <File Id="fil093D6D7CB723B5B62730D7B4E575F154" KeyPath="yes" Source="PQR.Some.dll" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="AppFiles">
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp78E9FF58917B1844F3E9315A285F3147" />
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: If you want to remove more than one element, just add more conditions to the match attribute:
    `<xsl:key name="kCompsToRemove" match="wi:Component[contains(wi:File/@Source, '.nupkg') or contains(wi:File/@Source, 'my-debug-file')]" use="@Id" />`